# why so quick on the Answer Ban?

Tags: discussion, reputation, answers, privileges, post-ban

I have had literally 1 post since joining that I immediately deleted because it didn't fit the format of an "answer'. When trying to share the solution that helped me on a thread asking the same question with no response I found out I have an answer ban? I just want to share this solution with the other struggling! How am I supposed to improve my reputation with good answers/ upvotes if I cannot post anything but questions to do so?

Comment: how many [deleted recent answers do you see here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/3244924)?

Comment: I've only deleted 1 answer ever. The only answer I've ever given. Was deleted because it was a question posted as answer on accident.

Comment: @HDE226868 this page is private, visible only to user and moderators

Comment: think of it as a typical login form. There's a field for user name (think of "question" field here at Stack Overflow), password ("answer" field here) and captcha ("comments" field). If you enter your name or captcha into password field, system won't let you in. That's what happened to your deleted answers. If you happen to make too much attempts to do it wrong, system will think you try to abuse it and will block you. That's what happened after you failed to enter correct stuff into "answer" field three times. The difference with login is that failing it is only your personal problem...

Comment: ...failing login is only your personal problem, as opposed to what happens when you enter wrong stuff into "answer" field over here. That's because answers are intended to be read by others. If you think of other readers, they expect an answer to the question over there, and when they see another question or comment instead, they get disappointed and frustrated. That is, block serves to protect other readers from harm brought in by your attempts to post stuff into the place where they expect to be an answer

Answer (score 13):

You didn't just post one answer to receive the ban. You've got 3 total answers over the course of your time on Stack Overflow.

The [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941269/empty-url-in-sitemapnode/21408361#21408361) (10k only) you posted contains:

> [image]

This is a comment to another answer and it was converted to comment. Answers are supposed to be answers to the question not comments to other answers.

The [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22050070/auto-increment-id-value-in-xml-file/29415608#29415608) (10k only) was:

> [image]

Again you used the answer box to ask a question about how to alter the solution for your situation. As a result, this was deleted.

The [final answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022992/how-to-get-avaudioplayer-output-to-the-speaker/29525710#29525710) (10k only) was:

> [image]

You deleted this after someone commented that it was a question not an answer to the asked question.

In all three of these cases, you didn't use the "Your Answer" box correctly. You should only be posting answers to the question asked, not comments or follow-up questions. You didn't hit the answer ban from one answer, it's the combination of all of your answers that lead to the ban. The post you deleted yesterday was the final nail to place a ban on your account.

We expect the content that is posted inside of the answer box to be an answer to the question. If you have a question, then you should Ask a New Question. Don't use the answer box to ask a question or to comment to another user.

I'd suggest reading [Why are answers no longer being accepted from my account?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans) which contains some tips to help you get out of the answer ban.

As for posting comments, you've got to [earn that privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) which comes with 50 reputation. You get more privileges by earning it.

Comment: Interesting.. It seems the only "bad" answer I provided was the one I deleted. The other 2 seem like any other question that would be asked here. Both older posts are in fact questions, in turn, answered helpfully by users of Stack Exchange. I'm confused how such questions could not be "well received"?

Comment: And after looking deeper into it the links you've provided are to questions I've asked or comments on answers, not answers. I've only ever posted 1 answer... Ever... On accident.

Comment: @Unconquered82 The answer box is to be used for answers only. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941269/empty-url-in-sitemapnode/21408361#21408361) is a comment on another answer. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22050070/auto-increment-id-value-in-xml-file/29415608#29415608) is asking how to alter the solution for your case. The last one you deleted because it was a question not an answer.

Comment: @Unconquered82 I think you don't fully understand how these sites work. You shouldn't be asking questions in the "Your Answer" box, if you have a question then you [Ask your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You've posted questions and comments as answers to other users question, that's not correct.

Comment: I understand that fully, which is exactly why I opted to delete it. It was done in error. So the ban is for that one instance? I don't get banning someone for 1 bad answer. I've only ever answered 1 question

Comment: @Unconquered82 The ban is because you've posted 3 total answers all of them have been deleted for a variety of reasons. The ban only came into effect after you deleted that last answer.

Comment: That's interesting, I don't see anything of the sort reflecting on my profile. Just 1 comment from "a long time ago" in 2014. Can you tell me where these answers are? I've got no reference of them anywhere in my profile. How a I supposed to up my reputation enough to up vote and/or comment if I'm no longer allowed to provide answers? Ask questions I already know the answer to?

Comment: So we can also not comment on solutions that aren't really solutions? I was simply correcting the solution. Comments can be down voted as well? You told me I've given 3 answers that were bad answers. Now I'm understanding that you're telling me I've had 1 bad answer and a comment of which the answer was deleted. And this is enough to warrant a ban? I'm not trying to be a nuisance, I'm just trying to understand why this happened with such little activity. I finally have a solution that might really help another person with the same answer and I'm not able to provide a quality answer.

Comment: you can comment, but not with the answer box. When you have 50 rep you can comment anywhere.

Comment: @bluefeet this post doesn't show any comment/answer from me at all.. Something has to be wrong..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22050070/auto-increment-id-value-in-xml-file/29415608#29415608

Comment: @Unconquered82 I've added some more details to my answer as well as screenshots of the answers that you posted.

Comment: Thank you for the info @bluefeet. I see the misuse now. Sorry about that! I'm not sure why I used it that way but I understand the ban now

Comment: consider [edit]ing to expand the explanation with "login form" analogy in [comments above](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253109/why-so-quick-on-the-answer-ban#comment826741_253109). I'd post it as a separate answer but question is closed and frankly I don't feel inclined to vote reopen