# Uplifting a ban

Tags: discussion, post-ban

How am I supposed to uplift a ban if I do not have access to previous "answers" I've left?

A moderator recently told me I left 3 answers that were unsatisfactory. I can't find a reference to these answers anywhere on my profile whatsoever. So my question remains. If we are not permitted to answer questions, our rep is not high enough to up vote or comment, what are we supposed to do in order to get the ban removed? It seems like a death sentence for this site and a little excessive in my case for 1 bad answer that I removed myself because it was made in error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really feel that you are frustrated with the answer left on your previous question: [why so quick on the Answer Ban?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253109/why-so-quick-on-the-answer-ban).

> If we are not permitted to answer questions, our rep is not high enough to up vote or comment, what are we supposed to do in order to get the ban removed?

Ummm... What about editing? You can still edit other people's posts as it is not required that you need more than 1 rep to edit. As approved edits give you 2 rep each, try to find posts that need editing and edit it. Edits can really help with the question and answer quality of Stack Overflow and other fellow sites. This can help you quickly get the ban lifted automatically, ***especially if you edit answers***. Editing answers will let the system know that you know what an answer is supposed to look like now.

Asking? You haven't mentioned about a question ban being applied here. Asking good-quality question will get you some of the first few privileges fast. 5 points of each upvotes, which can accumulate to a lot of rep on your way, plus new privileges.

Of course, @Darth Melkor's answer is absolutely right as well.

Comment: Edit what? A comment? That's all I have access to as I've deleted the only answer I've left

Comment: Edit other people's posts of course!

Comment: Forgive my frustration.. I'm not trying to be rude, I just don't understand how to go about correcting the situation since I don't have any answers currently that I can see

Comment: Well, for example you are allowed to edit anyone's answer, including mine and really any other post. Just keep editing and making good questions and you are out of that ban

Comment: I wasn't aware I could edit other users posts

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this to me. I'll do my best to fix things!

Comment: Please don't call names, it doesn't really matter who answered. And if you do call names, make sure you use the correct name.

Answer (score 4):

**[How can I get out of an answer ban?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/answer-bans)**

Your positive contributions to the site must outweigh your negatives.  You can start by fixing your answers, which I understand you should still be able to do.  If your answers can't be salvaged then my reading of this is that you can still gain positive contributions by asking questions.