# Problem with getting out of an answer ban

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I've been answer-banned today because of 3 poor answers, which I admit is my fault.

I read [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans), and [lots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253118/uplifting-a-ban) of [answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th/86998#86998) on Meta, and I think I understand how to get out of the answer ban.

I edited 1 of 3 poor answer which got me banned and made the deleted answer flagged, hoping someone would undelete it.

I also edited [another's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34093028/2927828), because the questioner wants a better solution than I have.

> I have also searched for alternative means for detection, but with no positive result. Perhaps **some light-weight parser becomes available in the future**. In the mean time, your answer at least helped solving my issue, so for now, it's accepted. Thanks. – Marten Koetsier Dec 4 '15 at 21:49

But the [answer I edited](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13633458) was rejected by [@Qirel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4535200/qirel), the reason being:

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

Yes, maybe he is right, but I can **neither comment nor answer**.

Should I have to find another question and try to edit an answer, hoping someone will accept it? If not, should I try again?

Comment: To get out of an answer ban you need to improve **your** answers, not other people's.

Comment: thanks for your advice, fortunately I can answer now. Should I close/delete this question?

Comment: The privileges like voting. commenting and flagging are there so the users first have a bit of experience *before* they are given that privilege so they don't mis-use the feature. Trying to circumvent those rules and privileges is never good, not in real life, nor here. You might want to query for [recent highly scored answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+%5Blaravel%5D+score%3A50+is%3Aa+created%3A1y) to get an idea what an answerable question and good answer look like.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Comment: Might be some forgotten deleted answers @ram

Comment: @Ramhound Deleting posts removes the reputation getting by the votes on them (both the up- and the downs).

Comment: Could anybody undelete this re-edited answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34308160/is-laravel-5-1-compatible-with-php-7/39423148#39423148

Comment: @monque it is deleted by a moderator so nor you nor 20K-ers can undelete it. You'll need to flag it for a moderator (the flag link is also where you found the edit link) and explain that you updated and improved the answer by addressing the issues raised  and that you think it is good enough to be undeleted.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the real lesson that needs to be learnt is *post better answers*. To be able to edit the questions of others well, *you need to be able to understand* what a good answer is, as well as the general "we we do things"

So, *post better answers*, improve those of those which don't make the grade, and most importantly, try to understand why your previous answers were good, and attempt to make your answers *great*.

I'd also suggest that if you don't realise you can flag your own answers for undeletion, it might be worth spending a little time reading through the site meta for the common practices of the site, and looking at highly upvoted questions to get a better idea of what sort of answers folk at the site expect.

It really feels like you're going about this the wrong way. Self improvement first, before you attempt to fix others.